# How to cancel OpenGL render by python In Blender

Tags: python, opengl, render, blender

when I press Opengl Animation icon in Blender VSE it executes and if I press escape it interrupts.

in code:

```
bpy.ops.render.opengl(animation=True, sequencer=True)
```

It works to start the animation render, but how to interrupt it using escape key? Should `KeyboardInterrupt` function be attached with it?

Edit:: after some research: I have found modal can do this. But can't figure out how to code this.

Comment: Add 'INVOKE_DEFAULT' as the first parameter, see [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14897/935).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I have already created the context layout. But stuck at modal. I can't find how to command opengl OP to stop. If the op starts it goes through all the frame then waits for the {'CANCELLED'} command. Is their any way to stop the command from python? I tried animation=False. But it doesn't stop when animation=True is going.

Comment: [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/71830/935) has a modal operator that does rendering.

Comment: Thanks for the source. Will try out with loop then. If got success, will post the the codes here. bookmarked.

Answer (score 2):

Almost forgot to post the solution. As sambler pointed out, that is the solution. 
From Blender 2.8 it is simply:

```
bpy.ops.render.opengl('INVOKE_DEFAULT', animation=True, sequencer=True)
```